# Add flex div to hero and invert position on resize

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As the title says, what i'm trying to achieve ( only 2 resolutions, 767px min/max )

- bigger than 767px, 2 divs side by side. One with text on the left side, one with an image on the right side.

  - The text has a fixed position( the font changes on resize), the image moves with the resize
  - The image can go behind the text, hence on a lower z-index
- smaller or 767px, use the bootstrapper out-of-the-box functionality and place them on top of each other

  - but inverted ( the image on the first row, text on second), without overlapping
    [image: my responsive scenario]

I can achieve either one or the other... never both. Having the text div has absolute position and the image as flex with `transform: translateX(50%)` was my best approach, but it doesn't seem right.
I'm gonna simplify the code for a better read.

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-md-row-reverse {
    flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
  }
  .order-md-1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .order-md-2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load bootstrap before custom css-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- hero -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row hero flex-md-row-reverse">
            <div class="hero-text col-md-6 order-md-1" >
                 MY TEXT
            </div>
            <div class="hero-img col-md-6 order-md-2">
                <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
```

to

```
flex-direction: row-reverse !important
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).